# SharedPreferences not reading the right context

Tags: java, android

I have a problem in my code , a method always return false even if i insert true

```
  public boolean isLoggedIn(){
        return pref.getBoolean("login", false);
    }
```

even if I add true before checking ,this code it will return false

```
  * */
    public void checkLogin(){
        // Check login status

        editor.putBoolean("login", true);// even if add true it will return false

        if(!this.isLoggedIn()){
            Toast.makeText(_context, " Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

what I am trying to do is having a `register` buttom in the action bar once click it will give the user register activity . then he will insert user name and password and returns him to mainactivity. if he click `register` button again it should send him to another activity because his login
in my code even if he is login it is sending him to register activity because the `false return` that i explained above the below is my code

sessionmanager

```
public class SessionManager {
    // Shared Preferences
    SharedPreferences pref;

    // Editor for Shared preferences
  //  Editor editor;

    // Context
    Context _context;

    // Shared pref mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    // Sharedpref file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "AndroidHivePref";

    // All Shared Preferences Keys
    private static final String IS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";

    // User name (make variable public to access from outside)
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";

    // Email address (make variable public to access from outside)
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    //SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    // Constructor
    public SessionManager(Context context){
        this._context = context;
       // pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    /**
     * Create login session
     * */
    public void createLoginSession(String name, String email){
        // Storing login value as TRUE
        Toast.makeText(_context, "Create", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        System.out.println("login1");
        editor.putBoolean("login", true);
        System.out.println(pref.getBoolean("login", false));
        // Storing name in pref
        editor.putString("name", name);

        // Storing email in pref
        editor.putString("email", email);
        // commit changes
        editor.commit();
    }

    /**
     * Check login method wil check user login status
     * If false it will redirect user to login page
     * Else won't do anything\
     * */
    public void checkLogin(){
        // Check login status
      //  editor.putBoolean("login", true);
        editor.putBoolean("login", true);

        if(!this.isLoggedIn()){
            Toast.makeText(_context, " Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // user is not logged in redirect him to Login Activity
            Intent i = new Intent(_context, Register.class);
            // Closing all the Activities
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            // Add new Flag to start new Activity
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            // Staring Login Activity
            _context.startActivity(i);
        }
else {
            Intent i = new Intent(_context, UserProfile.class);
            // Closing all the Activities
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            // Add new Flag to start new Activity
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            // Staring Login Activity
            _context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }



    /**
     * Get stored session data
     * */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
        // user name
        user.put(KEY_NAME, pref.getString(KEY_NAME, null));

        // user email id
        user.put(KEY_EMAIL, pref.getString(KEY_EMAIL, null));

        // return user
        return user;
    }

    /**
     * Clear session details
     * */
    public void logoutUser(){
        // Clearing all data from Shared Preferences


        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();

        // After logout redirect user to Loing Activity
        Intent i = new Intent(_context, MainActivity.class);
        // Closing all the Activities
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        // Add new Flag to start new Activity
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        // Staring Login Activity
        _context.startActivity(i);
    }

    /**
     * Quick check for login
     * **/
    // Get Login State
    public boolean isLoggedIn(){
        return pref.getBoolean("login", false);
    }
}
```

mainactivity part where I am calling the register.java

```
case R.id.ic_register:
             //  session=  GlobalContext.getInstance().getSession();
              //  session.checkLogin();
                session.checkLogin();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Create a new account please", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Intent intent = new Intent(this, Register.class);
                //startActivity(intent);
                return true;
```

register

```
SessionManager session;
    Button btnLogin;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

       final AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

        session=  GlobalContext.getInstance().getSession();

        usernam = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        passw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Login Status: " + session.isLoggedIn(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Get username, password from EditText
                String username = usernam.getText().toString();
                String password = passw.getText().toString();

                // Check if username, password is filled
                if(username.trim().length() > 0 && password.trim().length() > 0){
                    // For testing puspose username, password is checked with sample data
                    // username = test
                    // password = test
                    if(username.equals("test") && password.equals("test")){

                        // Creating user login session
                        // For testing i am stroing name, email as follow
                        // Use user real data
                        session.createLoginSession("test", "test");

                        // Staring MainActivity
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();

                    }else{
                        // username / password doesn't match
                        alert.showAlertDialog(Register.this, "Login failed..", "Username/Password is incorrect", false);
                    }
                }else{
                    // user didn't entered username or password
                    // Show alert asking him to enter the details
                    alert.showAlertDialog(Register.this, "Login failed..", "Please enter username and password", false);
                }

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Try degugging if `public SessionManager(Context context){
        this._context = context;
       // pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }` called or not. I only see `session=  GlobalContext.getInstance().getSession();` and don't know if it constructs your sessionmanager variable?

Comment: I know that you got sample from http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/, and you will find it init the SessionManager as the following `session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());`

Comment: @BNK yes it was problem with context and I solved it  by creating a class for session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to perform commit, in order to save value in preference
so just after adding anything write **editor.commit()**, please check updated method

```
public void checkLogin(){
    // Check login status

    editor.putBoolean("login", true);// even if add true it will return false
    editor.commit();

    if(!this.isLoggedIn()){
        Toast.makeText(_context, " Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: it will, kindly try again.
After adding all value in preference using editor. do editor.commit